# Save table in hive with java spark sql from json array

Tags: java, json, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

```
    Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("/user/administrador/prueba_diario.txt").toDF();

    ds.printSchema();

    Dataset<Row> ds2 = ds.select("articles").toDF();

    ds2.printSchema();
    spark.sql("drop table if exists table1"); 
    ds2.write().saveAsTable("table1");
```

I have this json format

```
root
 |-- articles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- content: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- publishedAt: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- source: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- urlToImage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- totalResults: long (nullable = true)
```

I want to save the array articles as a hive's table with the arrays format

example of hive table that i want:

```
author (string)
content (string)
description (string)
publishedat (string)
source (struct<id:string,name:string>)
title (string)
url (string)
urltoimage (string)
```

The problem is that is saving the table just with one column named article and the contend is inside in this only column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit convoluted, but I found this one to work:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
ds.select(explode(col("articles")).as("exploded")).select("exploded.*").toDF()
```

I tested it on

```
{
  "articles": [
    {
      "author": "J.K. Rowling",
      "title": "Harry Potter and the goblet of fire"
    },
    {
      "author": "George Orwell",
      "title": "1984"
    }
  ]
}
```

and it returned (after collecting it into an array)

```
result = {Arrays$ArrayList@13423}  size = 2
 0 = {GenericRowWithSchema@13425} "[J.K. Rowling,Harry Potter and the goblet of fire]"
 1 = {GenericRowWithSchema@13426} "[George Orwell,1984]"
```

Comment: I did it and i had this error



Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(articles)`;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedStar.expand(unresolved.scala:275)

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your schema, it's an array not a struct. I'll try a a bit on my own.

Comment: @Bar fixed, should do what you want now

Comment: Yes, but it saves the data in a single column.
It should generate columns in hive as there are columns in the structure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you gave me an excellent solution!